# Windows App Studio App customizing in VS 2013 getting started

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

So basically I just opened the app source download from the app studio app builder site and there are a ton of errors, I bet it's simple to fix.

I just don't know what the first step are in term of fixing this.  These errors are not helpful.

Can someone explain what steps I should take to getting my app studio app to build through Visual Studio 2013?

[image: Error messages in Building process]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix it by these steps:

1. check if all the projects in your solution loaded.
2. check the references in your project, normal, warning? and check the version of references.
3. check other errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help the problem was the references were not loading.